# How to check the status of input method in NSTextInputClient?

Tags: macos, nstextview, nstextstorage, input-method-kit, nstextinput

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000929-50495), I can see that the input context will send one of the following methods to the text view.

- `insertText:replacementRange:`
- `setMarkedText:selectedRange:replacementRange:`
- `doCommandBySelector:`

In my testcase, when enabled an input method, `keyDown` can trigger `setMarkedText:selectedRange:replacementRange`, but if I keep deleting `markedText` until the last character, then the input method will be deactivated without triggering any methods above.

Is there anything like a hook for the deactivation, so that I can do something immediately once input method deactivated?

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke thank you for the suggestion! I have found the solution below : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from [Chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/06d2c3f420d7f43b90a5e93a79231b1983412934/content/app_shim_remote_cocoa/render_widget_host_view_cocoa.mm#L1023).

When an input method enabled, user keep typing or deleting, with the IME window showing under the caret. `NSTextInputClient` will send key event, and input context will invoke `setMarkText`.

The problem is, when user delete the last character of the `markedText`, IME window disappearing, key event is sent and input context **won't invoke `setMarkText`**. As a result, `markedText` won't be cleared either (which should be an empty string as I expected).

Chromium's solution is very straight forward. Just clear the `markedText` every time when `keyDown`, and let `setMarkText` do the work. If `markedText` is empty, meaning input context deactivated input method and didn't invoke `setMarkText`.

Well, I think the API is somewhat inconsistent though...